# How to retrieve the type of element from typed array with undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of type `X[] | undefined`, I want to extract `X` type from it and use it after.

what I have tried is:

```
type X = typeof X[number]
```

but it gives syntax error because of the undefined.

Comment: Presumably you want `NonNullable<typeof X>[number]` but could you make the code here a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  Right now if I paste that I get that `X` is not found.

Comment: NonNullable has solved it, this was what i was searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the `undefined` from the type first. You can use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
declare const X: string[] | undefined
type XItem = NonNullable<typeof  X>[number]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gDQFz0xgEsUBzAbQF14AfeAVxVADMSRgBYAKAwE8AHBNgCSGEAFt4AXngA5VLPoRoAIwggAPH0FJm8HAD5yKeuJUgYlbkA)